# React Create a Horizontal Divider with Text In between

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, divider

I need to create a React component that is a Horizontal Divider with a content like text In between. All the resources I have online is unable to help me get this done. I tried a material-ui divider by creating a Divider component and placing my text in-between like the example below:

```
<Divider>Or</Divider>
```

But I get the error:

```
hr is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
```

I need to achieve this in the image below:

[image: Display a horizontal Divider]

Any help will be appreciated.

These are my codes below:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
 import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
 import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';

 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   root: {
   width: '100%',
   maxWidth: 360,
   backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
 },
 }));

 export default function ListDividers() {
 const classes = useStyles();

 return (
 <List component="nav" className={classes.root} aria-label="mailbox 
 folders">

  <Divider>Or</Divider>

  </List>
  );
 }
```

Comment: If you check out the document of [MUI Divider API](https://material-ui.com/api/divider/) you would find that it does not accept children. Maybe you need to write this component by your own

Comment: @keikai I have edited my question with the codes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here a custom example of what you could do : [repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xuqvvt?file=index.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  return <Divider>Or</Divider>;
};

const Divider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="border" />
      <span className="content">
        {children}
      </span>
      <div className="border" />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And the CSS:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.border{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit but your answer was a great start for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

**Using Material UI.**

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  border: {
    borderBottom: "2px solid lightgray",
    width: "100%"
  },
  content: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(0.5),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(0.5),
    paddingRight: theme.spacing(2),
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: 22,
    color: "lightgray"
  }
}));

const DividerWithText = ({ children }) => {
 const classes = useStyles();
 return (
  <div className={classes.container}>
    <div className={classes.border} />
    <span className={classes.content}>{children}</span>
    <div className={classes.border} />
  </div>
 );
};
export default DividerWithText;
```

You can import and use it like the below

```
<DividerWithText>Or</DividerWithText>
```

**Result**
[image: material ui divider with text at center]

Answer (score 10):

Update 29/03/2022

That's now possible with Material UI

https://mui.com/components/dividers/#dividers-with-text

---

You may want different spacing sometime

```js
<Divider spacing={1}>Hello World</Divider>
```

Or

```js
<Divider spacing={2}>Hello World</Divider>
```

For a configurable `spacing` here a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mamadOuologuem/d1df9d6e586cb4e5e8c376d7f0f18db9)

Or a [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-divider-with-text-pzyjd) in codesandbox if you prefer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The current answer causes any text with spaces in-between to wrap:
[image]

If that happens, changing width: 100% to flexGrow: 1 should solve it:

```
  border: {
    borderBottom: "2px solid lightgray",
    flexGrow: 1,
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for now, having `Divider` with text on it in MUI is only available in v5, which is still in alpha stage. If you would like to try, you can download the alpha package, but be warned that it is still highly unstable and a lot of changes might be needed to migrate to v5, which is not very worth it.

GitHub discussion: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24036